# GuidLine относительно другого объекта

Tags: java, android, xml

Нужно сделать GuidLine относительно другого объекта, а не относительно экрана. Пока я использую это:

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.875"
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких целей вообще можно использовать Barrier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#AAA"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#DDD"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="left_text_view,right_text_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

в этой строке:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="left_text_view,right_text_view"
```

вы указываете относительно каких объектов вы будете выравниваться. [Вот есть хороший](https://riggaroo.dev/constraintlayout-guidelines-barriers-chains-groups/#:%7E:text=Barriers%20are%20one%20of%20my,width%20of%20the%20referenced%20items.) туториал по вашему вопросу.